# Selenium WebElement getCssValue background colour misrepresented?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver for automating functional testing on a javascript based web application.
The javascript code (knockout.js) sets one of the OPTION elements for a SELECT dropdown lists to a different colour #FFFFCC, which is rgba(255, 255, 204, 1) (light yellow) (as verified by firebug).

My code for use by selenium is as follows:

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("views"))); // get the select
    List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions(); // get all the options

    for (WebElement option : allOptions) { //iterate over the options
      if (option.getCssValue("background-color").compareToIgnoreCase("rgba(255, 255, 204, 1)") == 0) {
         // do something 
      }
    }
```

But that if statement always fails. When I do a system.out.println() to the value of `option.getCssValue("background-color")` it returns 'transparent' for all my option elements and 'rgba(51, 153, 255, 1)' for my modified option element, which when converted to hex is #3399FF (a blue colour).

Why is selenium reporting the incorrect hex value for this element?

Comment: So are you checking for `background-color` or just the `color` of the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a good theory about why this problem happens, and it seems reproducible.

The blue color is the colour of the elements background when highlighted by a mouse. Selenium seems to pick up that colour instead of the actual background colour of the dropdown option.

Perhaps i should report that as a bug or unintended feature to the devs.